# I want to create a function like onbeforeunload for the submit of my page

Tags: javascript, html, events

In my site I have many href and button that relocate the page you are in. I thought that, since you can't modify the body of the alert created with onbeforeunload, I can make my own type but my questions are:

1. Can I intercept when the page is relocated inside my site without onBeforeUnload or onUnload?
2. Can I make a function wait until a button i pressed?
3. Is it possible to intercept some other changes of the browser page like if the user try to close it?
4. Is it possible to disable the entire page and leave only a toast be available?

Comment: What do you mean by toast? Also, you can make a function 'wait' until a button press using event listeners.

Comment: A css class made by bootstrap